# how do I install an SDK using require, when I need to require an folder and this seems impossible?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, installation, requirejs, facebook-javascript-sdk

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION.**
I'm trying to follow https://github.com/lucascosta/facebook-js-ads-sdk to install the Javascript SDK for Facebook. **Before anyone objects**, I am absolutely aware of the compact version (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart), but that API is absolutely useless to me. I need the one produced by Lucas Costa, in order to be able to make changes to my ads account, which the recommended script by Facebook does not enable.

As usual installation instructions (see github.com/lucascosta/facebook-js-ads-sdk) are horribly predicated on mysterious conditions, that are unbeknown to me. I cannot get the SDK to work and **would like someone to tell me explicitly what to do**. The crux of the problem is the paradoxical situation: I am supposed to use a `require('...')` command (where??) to include the SDK (where is this supposed to be saved??) and yet require *cannot* be used on folders, but on scripts. Maybe somewhere there is a `require.config` file, I'm supposed to set up, but I have no idea, as, like I said, the instructions completely bypass any mention of the necessary starting conditions.

Here is what I have done so far. My folder-structure looks like this (I don't even know if this is right, as no-one explains it anywhere!):

```
[Serverroot]
  — [folder with my website]
      – facebook-ads-sdk (the folder one gets by downloading)
      – css — pagestyles.css
      – js — lib
              require.js
           — app
              ( some header scripts )
      – img
              ( some images )
      index.php
```

In `index.php` I have a block of html followed by some javascript. It is here, that I try to insert the setup / example code from . The browser cannot even get past the line `const adsSdk = require('facebook-ads-sdk');`. I have tried a number of things: `require('./facebook-ads-sdk');`, moving all this to the folder `./js/app` in a script `main.js` and then writing in my html in `index.php` where `main` and `require` are located. Setting up a `require.config` (or `requirejs.config`) replacing `require` by `requirejs`, etc. and including the appropriate scripts in the `<head>` part of `index.php`. Nothing helps. Here are the errors: first with `const adsSdk = require('facebook-ads-sdk');` I get

```
Error: Module name "facebook-ads-sdk" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

Okay. How do I ‘load the Module for the context _’?? Reading requirejs.org/docs/start.html is of no help here. I tried `require([], function() {require('facebook-ads-sdk')});` Same error. I tried `require(['facebook-ads-sdk']);`

I tried using the following commands in my script in `index.php`:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'facebook': {
            exports: 'adsSdk',
        },
    },
    paths: {
        'sdk': './facebook-ads-sdk',
    }
});
var adsSdk = require(['sdk']);
```

Then I get the error

```
Failed to load resource: http:// .... /facebook-ads-sdk.js the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

*Ie*, the browser thinks I'm trying to include a script `facebook-ads-sdk.js`, but I’m supposed to(???) ‘require’ the entire folder! What is going on? **Can someone please give me thorough instructions about the necessary folder structure and command, in order to get this SDK working?**

Why is this so infuriatingly vaguely described online? Is there some kind of mysterious way of installing SDKs, about which ‘everyone’ knows, but never mentions?

---

**UPDATE:  SOLUTION.** For any future google-searches for this same problem: via the following simple methods, one can install & embed the Javascript-FB-Ads-SDK:

1. install via `npm install --save facebook-ads-sdk` a copy of the npm modul Lucas Costa’s facebook-ads SDK.
2. Copy this folder to your website’s architecture (actually you possibly just need one subfolder / file).
3. in your HTML include the script (via `<script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>`) with the src pointing to the file in the facebook-ads-sdk folder: **`/dist/iife.js`**.
4. In your page’s script, you now have access to then API via the global variable **`fb`**.

alternatively to 3:

3’. in your HTML headers make sure to include the `require.js` script via a `<script>`-tag. Then in your website’s javascript apply the following commands anywhere:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'sdk': './[FOLDERNAME OF SDK]/dist/iife',
    }
});
require(['sdk']);
```

Credit and special thanks goes to **@SLaks** and **@KhauriMcClain** (I would give you up-points if I could) for this solution.

Comment: Are you running in a browser or in NodeJS? Are you using npm?

Comment: On a browser. Tried it with and without a local copy of npm. How am I supposed to use require on an entire folder?

Comment: You should load it the same way you load the rest of your code, as described in the first paragraph: `ECMAScript 5 bundled minified distribuitions with sourcemaps are also available as AMD and CommonJS modules, as an IIFE (under the fb variable), as UMD if you want it all, and even as Browser Globals.`

Comment: How are you loading your JS code? Are you using npm packages with  browserify or webpack?

Comment: what minified sdks? Facebook offers one, but it’s useless. I need this SDK.

Comment: All code is loaded in the html headers within index.php.

Comment: You probably need to build it first to get the "dist" folder. Inside that dist folder you'll find the scripts you can require using  requirejs.

Comment: `ECMAScript 5 bundled minified distribuitions with sourcemaps are also available as AMD and CommonJS modules, as an IIFE (under the fb variable), as UMD if you want it all, and even as Browser Globals.` I don’t even know where to begin with this…

Comment: build what? how? If I can get a min-js out of this nightmare SDK, that would be brilliant. Is this possible? And why doesn’t it just… work how Lucas Costa (very vaguely) describes?

Comment: All of their instructions are assuming a bundler (browserify or webpack), which you should probably use.  If you want to keep using plain `<script>` tags, you'll probably find a minified file somewhere in the `npm insall`ed package, which will create a set of global variables if loaded in a `<script>`.  Use the dev tools to find the globals.

Comment: Okay, I’ll have a look…

Comment: Oh boy, that's another question in itself. To get started you should Install nodejs and node package manager (npm). Clone the repo, then per the development section of the readme install gulp and bower. Then run `npm install` then `bower install` then `gulp dist` and then a dist folder will be built. Inside you'll probably want the cjs.js file. That's the file you need to require. I'd say try looking for a pre-built version online before doing all that though

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz3qX.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcRNo.png

Comment: @KhauriMcClain see the first image. That script is there. Do I just have to ’require’ `cjs.js`? Can I then just scrap the rest? If that works (who knows) what is the point of this, why don’t they just post 1 script instead of an entire folder?

Comment: That's good. If you have that dist folder then you can just grab the global.js one and include it in a script tag in your html/php file and use it without requiring it. I'm assuming you might have only used require because it was in the examples on the github.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain exactly: I was just following the instructions. As SLaks points out below, I’m not trying to go out of my way to use require : ) I’ll try this. Why do they go through all this bother—1 minified script would suffice. Facebook offers one, but it sadly lacks all the features that this SDK offers. I simply don’t get why people can’t make compact easy to install products.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain okay, so those scripts are loading. I now get `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at globals.js:3` (similarly with `cjs.js`). What do I need to include to get `exports` to work? I already have included before this `require.js`…

Comment: @Thomas: Try `iife.js`

Comment: @Thomas: Because most non-trivial applications use bundlers (managing a large codebase with nothing but `<script>` tags is a nightmare).  If you use a bundler, their instructions are extremely simple (npm install, then `require` it from any file).

Comment: Oops. SLaks is right. Instead of using globals.js use iife.js and the sdk will be global under the variable name `fb`

Comment: Amazing! using *just* `iif.js` worked. Thanks @SLaks & @KhauriMcClain !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions are assuming that you're using a bundling system like Webpack or Browserify.
If you are, the instructions "just work"; you can `require()` it and everything will work fine.

If you're building a non-trivial codebase, you really should use such a system.

If you aren't, you can reference `iife.js` in a `<script>` tag and that will create global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you are using require.

1. You cannot use the synchronous require method to load dependencies if they have not been loaded before. Hence `const adsSdk = require('facebook-ads-sdk');` will not work. You will need to use the form `require(['name-of-script'], callback)`.
2. Require does not allow you to load an entire folder. You have to find the exact script you are trying to work with so `var adsSdk = require(['sdk']);` will not work.

Ultimately your code should look something like:

`require(['some-facebook-script'], function(someFacebookScript) {
   // Do some work here
});`

The parameter passed to the callback function will be the loaded module you are trying to consume. When using the asynchronous version (as I just demonstrated) the return from require is not useful.

Comment: You're assuming he is actually using / wants to use requirejs.  I doubt that.

Comment: I just want to get the SDK to work. The only method I know is via require, but I can’t even get require to work, as the instructions are stupidly geared to me requiring a folder and not a script.

Comment: Most of the questions revolve around usage of require and "installing" the sdk. He is clearly using this in a browser. Using other AMD loaders doesn't seem to be in the scope of this conversation.

Comment: @NathanMontez: No; he wants to use a raw `<script>` tag and no bundling or loaders at all.

Comment: Fair enough. I think the preferred method should be to use require if no additional build steps are desired.

Comment: @NathanMontez if you can show me how implement require(…) WITH a thorough explanation regarding file structure AND in the context of installing THIS sdk (see my post: no-one explains this properly online—one can only find fragments of information for certain cases, but nothing that explains it all), then that would be VERY useful. *Ie*, if you can install the javascript sdk for a context very similar to mine, then great.

Comment: I figured it out. It goes together with @SLak’s solution.

Comment: Quote: _Require does not allow you to load an entire folder._ So why on the website do they instruct one to use commands of the form
`const adsSdk = require('facebook-ads-sdk');` , whereby 'facebook-ads-sdk‘ is an entire folder?